# Slow XA transactions in JBoss

Tags: sql-server, jboss, transactions, query-optimization, newrelic

We are running jboss 4.2.2 with SQL server 2005 (sqljdbc driver 1.2).

We have recently installed new relic and can see a large bottleneck with our transactions.

Generally for any one web request the bottleneck of sits on one of these:

- `master..xp_sqljdbc_xa_start`
- `master..xp_sqljdbc_xa_commit`
- `org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection()`
- `master..xp_sqljdbc_xa_end`

Several hundred ms are spent on one of these items (in some cases several seconds). Cumulatively most of the response time is spent on these items.

I'm trying to indentify whether its any of the following:

- Will moving away from XA transactions help?
- Is there a larger problem at my database that I dont have visibility over?
- Can I upgrade my SQL driver to help with this?
- Or is this an indication that there are just a lot of queries, and we should start by looking at our code, and trying to lower the number of queries overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XA transactions are necessary if you are performing work against more than one resource in a single transaction, if you need consistency then you need XA. However you are talking in terms of "queries" which might imply that you are mostly doing read-only activities, and so XA may be overkill. Furthermore you don't speak about using multiple databases or other transactional resources so do you really need XA at all?

So first step: understand the requirements, do you need transaction scopes that span several database interactions? If you are just doing a single query then XA is not needed. If you have mixture of activities needing XA and simple queries not needing XA then use two different connections, one with XA and one without - this clarifies your intention. However I would expect XA drivers to use single resource optimisations so that if XA is not needed you don't pay the overhead so I suspect something more is going on here. (disclaimer I don't use JBoss so my intuition is suspect).

So look to see whether your transaction scopes are appropriate, isolation levels are sensible and so on. Are you getting contention because transactions are unreasonably long, for example are transactions held over user think time?

Next those multi-second waits: that implies contention (or some bizarre network issue) The only reason I can think of for an xa_start being slow is that writing a transaction log is taking unreasonably long - are your logs perhaps on some slow network device? Waits for getConnection() might simply imply that your connection pool is too small (or you're holding connections for too long) If xa_commit and xa_end are taking a long time I'd want to know what the resource managers are doing, can you get any info from the database server.

My overall position: If you truly need XA then you will pay some logging and network message overheads, but these should not be costing you hundreds or thousands of millseconds. Most business systems need XA in a small subset of their overall resource accesses typically when updating two otherwise independent systems, and almost never in read-only scenarios - absolute consistency across distributed systems is pretty much meaningless so using XA for queries is almost certainly overkill.